# Is there a good software for managing a private agenda ? (open-source if possible)

Tags: php, calendar, cloud, mariadb

I'm looking for an agenda/calendar app that would allow creating events for an organisation, which is divided into groups/sections. The requirements are :

1. being able to add contacts to zero, one or more sections.
2. that events can be made either public, only visible to all contacts, or visible to contacts belonging to one or more specific sections.

The software can either be cloud-based (reasonably priced if not FOSS) or able to be set up on a mutualized hosting space running php (at OVH) and MariaDB. We tried Framagenda already but, sadly, it doesn't allow to invite all members of a section to an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will do:
https://github.com/Dallas-Makerspace/calendar
or this
https://github.com/sabre-io/Baikal

Both should fill the requirements i believe.